# Why does my asciidoc relative link doesn't work outside of my microservice?

Tags: docker, microservices, relative-path, asciidoc

I'm starting to create documentation using asciidoc on my project which is following a microservices architecture.
We have a microservice for documentation. In its files I want to link to another document in another microservice.
I can do a relative link inside my own component but when I try to go higher with ../ it does not work and the link does nothing.

Does anyone may know why ?

Could it be because asciidoc is installed in the jenkins file of my component but not the others ? 
Or is it because I do not use the link correctly ?

I use it as it is describe in the doc :

`link:../other_microservice/other-document.asciidoc[]`

I also tried the xref with no more success.

Thanks a lot for anyone who can help me

Comment: "I use it as it is describe in the doc": Can you link to the doc you're talking about ?

Answer (score 1):

The `link:` macro is supposed to be used with a URL, not a file path. Generally, it does what you mean. However, Asciidoctor's safe mode prevents access to files which reside outside of the folder containing the source file specified for transformation.

So, if the documentation for your other microservices is going to be hosted separately (e.g. one URL per microservice), then you should update your `link:` macro usage to specify URLs instead.

If all of your microservice documentation is to be hosted under one URL, specify `--safe` when you invoke Asciidoctor. For more details, see:: https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#running-asciidoctor-securely